# Raw expression broken

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuetify.js

Can someone help me with this error?
I couldn't find the why to the bellow message.

The code:

```
 :label="` ${$t('cadastros.clientes.edit.status')}: ${cliente.status === true ? ${$t('cadastros.clientes.edit.ativo')} : ${$t('cadastros.clientes.edit.inativo')}}`"
```

The error:

```
Errors compiling template:

      invalid expression: Unexpected token '{' in
    
        ` ${$t('cadastros.clientes.edit.status')}: ${cliente.status === true ? ${$t('cadastros.clientes.edit.ativo')} : ${$t('cadastros.clientes.edit.inativo')}}`
    
      Raw expression: :label="` ${$t('cadastros.clientes.edit.status')}: ${cliente.status === true ? ${$t('cadastros.clientes.edit.ativo')} : ${$t('cadastros.clientes.edit.inativo')}}`"
```

I'm using locale to translate and vue/vuetify to code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this?

```
:label="` ${$t('cadastros.clientes.edit.status')}: ${
  cliente.status === true
  ? $t('cadastros.clientes.edit.ativo')
  : $t('cadastros.clientes.edit.inativo')
}`"
```

Comment: Aww thank you! It was passed unnoticed. Maybe it's time for a break kk